# Finding AMI ids for Redhat images on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, redhat, amazon-ami

Is there exists any way for finding ami-ids of specific version of Fedora?
For example, 6.3, 6.4 and so on?

Answer (score 2):

See: [Finding a Linux AMI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/finding-an-ami.html)

It lists many ways to find Linux AMIs. To find an AMI using CLI:

[Finding an AMI Using the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/finding-an-ami.html#finding-an-ami-aws-cli)

```
aws ec2 describe-images --owners 309956199498 --filters 'Name=name,Values=RHEL-7.5_HVM_GA*' 'Name=state,Values=available' --output json | jq -r '.Images | sort_by(.CreationDate) | last(.[]).ImageId'
```